# webpack -p not running on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a big project which I was trying to reduce in size using webpack-p according to here: https://hackernoon.com/reduce-webpack-bundle-size-for-production-880bb6b2c72f

I could not run it as I was encountering problems when running webpack -p (it threw an error on every function of index.js

I thought it might be something with my packages. I decided to create new create-react-app and run the command there. To my surprise, there I get the same error:

[image: Error encountered]

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have a config file because the command you are trying to run is global, it is not getting from your current working directory. Run `npm run build` instead, which does that under the hood, but has a lot of other things created by the contributors of `create-react-app`.

You could pass a config file for the global webpack cli, but you don't have access for that in your folder since it is "not" available for your. `npm run build` also already applies a lot of optimizations for you.

Comment: So how come my project compiled is still 3.5 Mb even though I do not have much in it (I am talking now about the big one, not the newly created app)

Comment: depends on a lot of factors, applying those optimizations won't reduce 3Mb of file...

Comment: Look for code splitting too, vendors chunk, all those things helps.

Comment: Also never install webpack nor webpack-cli globally.

Comment: Maybe because I did it I have this problem. Is npm uninstll webpack -g enough?

Comment: yes, it is enough. Always prefer to install locally and invoke through npm scripts

Comment: running cli to determine WHY and ANALYZE WHY the build is 3mb big is what we want to achieve here, not some drivel about how we should just run npm run build

Comment: @zuckerburg sorry but that was not the question. I asked what was specified.

Comment: @PlayMa256 "I have a big project which I was trying to reduce in size using webpack-p". Normally people who struggle with their primary objective and receives errors because of it, i.e, him trying to optimize his project and build, would ask how to solve the error, instead of being addressed to his original objective. It's like a doctor putting a plaster on a broken arm because you're complaining it's bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses [webpack v4](https://webpack.js.org) you must use `webpack --mode=production` instead of `webpack -p`.

Possible values for mode are: `none`, `development` or `production`.

Another usage:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  mode: 'production',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Doing webpack --mode=production thows "Insufficient number of arguments or entry found. Then there is ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'